# Opening a device file fails due to No such device or address

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module, chardev

I am trying to create a character device driver (kernel module).
The modue gets loaded, creates the character device as can be seen below:

```
    root@imx6x-std:~# ls -l /dev/socledchrdevregion
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      246,   0 Jan  1 08:56 /dev/socledchrdevregion
```

But when i try to open the device using a test application (the open function inside the driver doesn't do anything special apart from printing a debug message), i get an error:

```
root@imx6x-std:~# ./led_ioctltest
led_ioctltest: open /dev/socledchrdevregion failed due to No such device or addres
```

Following is the content of /proc/devices:

```
    root@imx6x-std:~# cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
 10 misc
 13 input
 29 fb
 81 video4linux
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
116 alsa
128 ptm
136 pts
153 spi
180 usb
189 usb_device
199 galcore
207 ttymxc
244 vuc_sim
245 vuc
246 socledchrdevregion
247 ubi0
248 mxc_src
249 mxc_vpu
250 conti_kmod_tracing
251 mxc_ipu
252 ptp
253 pps
254 rtc

Block devices:
259 blkext
 31 mtdblock
179 mmc
```

The device is present with major number is 246.

This is the way i try to open the device:

```
 #define DEVICE "/dev/socledchrdevregion"
fd = open(DEVICE, O_RDONLY);
```

This is a snippet of the LKM:

```
if ((ret = alloc_chrdev_region(&first, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME)) < 0)
{
        printk(KERN_ERR PRINTK_CONTEXT": FAILED TO ALLOCATE CHRDEVREGION \n");
        return -1;
}

printk(KERN_INFO PRINTK_CONTEXT": ALLOCATE CHRDEVREGION SUCCESS \n");

classptr = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "socledclass");
device_create(classptr, NULL, first, NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
printk(KERN_INFO "PRINTK_CONTEXT: DEVICE CREATED \n");
led_cdevptr = cdev_alloc();
led_cdevptr->ops = &led_fops;
```

Could anyone please help me in finding the error? I will post the complete code if necessary.

Comment: I don't know, but there's a chance that although the device file (a character special device) is present, it needs some hardware available that is not available (to you) on your machine.  Thus, although the device file name exists, the device that should be associated with it is not available, hence the error.

Comment: thanks for the comment, do you mean that the driver module is throwing an error or is it the linux driver framework thats throwing an error? I have implemented the driver module. So i can put some debug messages in the driver module and see. I can also present the complete code of the driver module here if it helps.
Hasn't anyone ever developed a dummy character device driver without a real associated hardware behind the device file?

Comment: I didn't appreciate that you'd written the driver. It might be the framework throwing the error.  I'm not sure; I don't have the relevant experience to give much help.  Yes, I'm sure you can write drivers that work in the absence of the hardware.  One example would be `/dev/null`.

Comment: ok thanks Jonathan, i will look further into it and update here if i find something. Meanwhile i also hope some one else gives me more hints about the problem.

Comment: Any one else has any idea about this problem?

Comment: using mknod  /dev/example c 250 0 will connect right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have registered your device with sysfs, which causes it to become visible (and for udev to create the device file). You did not, however, register the actual device. You got a major minor assigned, but they are not connected to your driver.

In all likelihood, you have skipped calling `cdev_add`.

In a nutshell, the sequence is:
`alloc_chrdev_region` gives you a range of major/minor device IDs you can use, that are guaranteed to be only for your device.

`cdev_add` register actual handlers for those IDs (you can call it without calling `alloc_chrdev_region` if your device has a preallocated region set to it, such as /dev/null or /dev/random).

Comment: Shemesh, thanks for your response, its true i forgot the cdev_add(). It seems i have lacked a basic understanding. I thought alloc_chrdev_region()  is responsible for allocating a character device region and also adding this to the kernel driver framework. But now looking at cdev_add function it seems i cdev_add is responsible for that.

Comment: @Shemesh, I couldn't edit my above comment, so i am adding a new one. Could you or anyone please explain me shortly what is the difference between "alloc_chrdev_region" and " cdev_add"